# Short story about two people writing back and forth and they can't stop because it's not polite to not respond

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

I can't remember where I read this. It's a short story about two people writing back and forth. They can't stop because it's not polite to not respond.

I think it ends with

> one tracking down the other and killing them.

Comment: Hi Corey, and welcome to lit SE. It's surprising how much help little details, seemingly irrelevant, can be in identifying stories. Can you have a check through [this list](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) and add whatever detail you can remember, even if a little vague? Eg, did you read it at school, what was the cover, was it a new book or second hand, was it in English? Did you find it on the tube just as it pulled into Piccadilly Circus and have felt vaguely guilty about not checking more carefully with other passengers before taking it? And so on.

Comment: Does "killing **them**" mean you don't remember if the characters were men or women? Do you remember their nationalities? Do you have any idea how old the story is, or how long ago you read it, say within a decade or two? Does the killer use a gun, a knife, a sword, their bare hands?